# Task 02: How does this Java Code work?

Tags: java

```
public class Learning {
    int i = 1; // i is assigned to 1.
    static int s = 2;// s is assigned to 2.

    Learning() {
        i = 0; s++; // i is assigned to 0 and s increases to 2. 
        System.out.println("test: " + i + s);// this line will display test: 03 since the values are above given.
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Learning t1 = new Learning();// Creating and instance variable from the Class Learning.
        System.out.println("t1: " + t1.i + t1.s);//t1 reaches with the help of the . the value of i as well as s and again this line will print out t1: 03
        t1.s = 6;// Now the variable get s new value which is 6
        Learning t2 = new Learning();// Creating another instance variable from the class called Learning
        t2.i = 8;// Now the value for i is set for 8.
        System.out.println("t2: " + t2.i + t2.s);// Now I thought the program would display t2: 86 since I have already got the value 8 and 6 assigned above, but it doesn't do that.
    }
}
```

Okay guys, as seen above I have got a new Java Code, I think all in all I did understand many things, at least I did comments above the stuff I understood and thought my way of thinking would be correct.

Feel free and check my above comments and correct me if I am wrong.

I have tested and the above code actually prints following:

```
test: 03
t1: 03
test: 07
t2: 87
```

So in other words I was partially right, I simply don't understand why it is printing test: 07, since there is no loop, and why t2: 87 is not t2: 86?

I was initially expecting something like that:

```
test: 03
t1: 03
t2: 86
```

Any profis wanting to check it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest that you study the difference between static and member variables.

Comment: Time to learn using debugger.

Comment: @Code-Guru, I learn best through examples. I hope there will be some knowledgeable and decent user who will help me through this code.

Comment: @user3330060 If you google "Java static variables", I'm sure you will find examples. Also, the Java tutorial is full of great examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Learning` is called every time you create a `new Learning()`, because it's the constructor for all instances of the Learning class. You create two instances of `Learning`, therefore `test` gets printed twice. The reason the value is `87` is because `s` is `static`. This means all instances of `Learning` share the same value for `s`. Therefore modifying `t1`'s instance of `s` to be `6` also modifies t2's instance of `s`, which then gets incremented in its constructor, and becomes `7`.

Answer (score 1):

It's printing `test: 07` because you are instantiating a new copy of `Learning()` as t2. Therefore, it's going in the constructor and printing the line in there.

Because it's being instantiated, this also increases the value of `s` in the constructor. Because `s` is a static variable, its value is shared among all `Learning` objects. Because you had set it to 6 in t1, it increases to 7 when you instantiate the new object, yielding '87'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you create 2 objects of the class learning, the "test: 0x" will print twice.

The reason why t2 is 86 and not 87 is because you first set `t1.s = 6` and, after that, call the constrctor `new Learning()`, which will increment `s` by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line: `Learning t2 = new Learning();`

This will cause `test: 07` to be printed out because it uses the Learning() constructor which has a print statement in it.

This line also causes s to increase by 1 from 6 to 7. This is why `t2:87` is printed instead of `t2:86`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create a new instance of `Learning` type, the constructor will be invoked. So when you create the `t2` object the `s` value is incremented by one(that's why you have the `87` value printed instead of `86` and the text `test: 07` is printed.